# Automatically select correct CodeAnalysis ruleset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, code-analysis, tfsbuild, fxcop

We have a number of large solutions and have a number of ruleset files based on the different project types. For example we have:

- A Sharepoint Rulesset containing:

  - Microsoft All Rules
  - MSOCAF rules
  - SPDisposeChecker rule
  - A number of custom rules
- A test project ruleset

  - Microsoft All Rules
  - Disabled a few naming guideline rules (the use of underscores for example)
  - A number of Test specific rules that similar to TypeMock TestLint
  - A number of custom rules
- A standard ruleset

  - Microsoft All Rules
  - A number of custom rules

I'd love it if Code Analysis were able to automatically select the right set based on the project type.

I haven't found the ideal way to do this. Things I'll consider:

- Drop a targets file in the msbuild folder of the build server which derives the project type based on the existence of specific build targets (yuk)
- Specify the CodeAnalayis Rules file in each target file for each project type (yuk)
- Create a custom Targets file and include that in every project, set a property in each project to select the correct project type. (yuk)
- Alter the rules themselves to know whether they're in the correct context (possible for 
  custom rules, not feasible for the default rules).

What we're currently doing:

- Specify the ruleset manually for each project.

I'd love to hear ideas for a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for most project types. Many of the default Msbuild targets provided by Microsoft include an option to load BeforeTargets and Aftertargets by placing the targets in question in a specific folder in the Msbuild folder structure.

I put a targets file into these folders (naming based on the way the project type expects them, these tend to differ from project type to project type) where I specify the default CodeAnalaysis.rules file. The project can still override these, but if it doesn't the default is used.

Sharepoint for example looks for this file:

`$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Custom.After.Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets`

These references are stored in msbuild properties such as `$(CustomAfterSharePointTargets)` which you can extend or override if wanted.

My solution is built [upon this feature](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780735659827/solution_import_files?reader=html&imagepage=) and [this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924404/msbuild-custom-after-microsoft-common-targets-for-native-c-projects-in-vs2010).

I put in a request to standardize this more in Visual Studio 11. [Please vote for it](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2793283-standardize-msbuild-wildcard-imports-for-before-af).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach would be to substitute either the Code Analysis targets file or build task with a version that allows for your inference.  Personally, I wouldn't be a fan of this since the interception point is a bit too hidden for my tastes, but ymmv...

If this is for a product that will be maintained over time by a single team, I would probably opt for something along the lines of your 3rd option.  On the other hand, if this is for a project where the code base would eventually be transfered to another team (whether internal or external), I would opt for something that can be done via the Visual Studio UI.  Unfortunately, that means project-specific ruleset selection.  The only good news is that there is a UI that allows this to be managed for all projects in a given solution (accessible from the Analyze...Configure Code Analysis for Solution menu).

Comment: I know of the manage solution thing, but since we have multiple project teams I'd much rather have a solution that can manage itself. There's been too many issues with incorrect rulesets, missing rulesets, altered rulesets. I'm not touching the default targets file, it's too much hidden and too easy to get lost during service packs and hotfixes.