# Is it possible to include by default project property sheets to new projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So that every time I create a project using the libraries I usually use I won't have to manually add the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but I advise against it. Main reason being it will make your project files unusable on other machines unless you also force your solution on them. Second reason you cannot expect *all* your projects ever are going to use the same libraries/versions/configurations of those libraries so after a while it might become unmaintainable.

You are imo better of creating a small utility which copies a project from a template you create with all imports and then changes guid and project name. Or create a template for VS which does that.

Anyway: a possible solution is to add an msbuild file which imports all default property sheets you need into the `$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\Win32\ImportBefore\` directory (create it if it doesn't exist). The file has to have a `.targets` extension. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3930270/128384) for example.