# Can I override the C++ language version in an Azure DevOps YAML file?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild

I have VS solutions with hundreds of C++ projects built using Azure Devops, these projects have a big mess of different project settings as projects have been created at different times over 2 decades, converted from different VS versions, etc.

We want to standardise some settings for instance building everything using c++17 standard. That's a compiler setting `cl.exe /std:c++17` but I cannot see any way we can override this via msbuild/YAML; I'd initially assumed I could set it as a project property `msbuild -p:std=c++17` but this isn't possible (for reasons I don't fully understand).

In another couple of years we might want to force all our code to build against the c++20 standard. Equally, we might want to compare builds flip-flopping between two settings. So: is there a way we can apply compiler settings at build-time which override the project-specific settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two approaches (other than editing all the project files individually):

1. Use switch `p:ForceImportAfterCppTargets` on the msbuild command-line. This allows a .props file to be specified which is evaluated and overrides project settings. More information here: [MSBuild: Custom.After.Microsoft.Common.targets for native C++ projects in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924404/msbuild-custom-after-microsoft-common-targets-for-native-c-projects-in-vs2010) and [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/modify-project-properties-without-changing-project-file?view=msvc-160)
2. Use directory-level file [Directory.Build.target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) file, this will be auto-discovered by msbuild and similarly override project settings.

The one downside is that these methods both seem to only apply to msbuild, not within Visual Studio itself, which can lead to confusion when something will build in the IDE but not on the build agent or vice versa.